# Trouble using gcheckboxgroup - use.table =TRUE (gWigets) (R)

Tags: r, gwidgets

I have a long list of elements that I want to display vertically as checkboxes in my GUI. 
Here is my code:

```
library(gWidgets)
library(gWidgetstcltk)


window <- gwindow("ITRAX Data Analysis")
Frame_Elements <- gframe( text="Elements", horizontal=FALSE, container=window)
Group7 <-ggroup(container = Frame_Elements, horizontal = TRUE)


Element_Options <- c( "Ac","Ag","Al", "Ar", "As", "At", "Au", "Ba", "Bi", "Br", "Ca", "Cd", "Ce", "Cl", "Co", "Cr", "Cs", "Cu", 
                  "Dy", "Er", "Eu", "Fe", "Fr", "Ga", "Gd", "Ge", "Hf", "Hg", "Ho", "I", "In", "Ir", "K", "La", "Lu", "Mg",
                  "Mn", "Mo", "Nb", "Nd", "Ni", "Os", "P", "Pa", "Pb", "Pd", "Pm", "Po", "Pr", "Pt", "Ra", "Rb", "Re", "Rh",
                  "Ru", "S", "Sb", "Sc", "Si", "Sm", "Sr", "Ta", "Tb", "Tc", "Te", "Th", "Ti", "Tl", "Tm", "U","V", "W", "Y",
                  "Yb", "Zn", "Zr")


Choose_Elements <- gcheckboxgroup(Element_Options, container = Group7, horizontal = FALSE, checked = FALSE, use.table = TRUE)
```

My problem is that the scroll table does not always open when I run the code. Sometimes I need to run it multiple times (without actually editing the code in any way) in order for the scroll box to appear. In other words, the window and frame of the GUI will appear, but will be empty.
Also, when the scroll box does open, the scroll bar doesn't actually work.

Any help with resolving this issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Might first comment was to use `gWidgets2`, which has better support under `tcltk`. However, I'm not sure this example works as expected. At first I see a sizing issue, and then I see an issue with icons on my local installation. I'll file a bug report on the gWidgets2tcltk issues page.

Comment: Okay, on master of `gWidgets2tcltk` on GitHub is a fix of the images. This can be installed through devtools. Like other table widgets, managing the size may need to be done via the `size<-` method.

Comment: @jverzani Could you please elaborate on what you mean by installing the fix of images on devtools. I am new to R and a bit lost. Thank you

Comment: Sure: `devtools` is a package that allows you to install other packages from `github` and not just from `CRAN`. I have pushed some changes to github but not yet to CRAN (which doesn't like lots of churn). To use these changes, you would install `devtools` and then load `devtools` then run this command `install_github("gWidgets2tcltk", "jverzani")`. This will update your package and it should work. (You may want to install `gWidgets2tcltk` first from CRAN, as it looks like you are using the older `gWidgetstcltk` installation.)

Comment: @jverzani Thank you very much for your help!